# Deleting a pointer returned from a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I'm writing doing a coding assignment for school that requires us to use arrays instead of vectors (the point is to learn about pointers and memory management). The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to delete a pointer returned from a function -- below is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
int* rndFunc(){
    int *rndValue = new *int[5];

    return rndValue;
}
int main(void){
    int *foo;
    foo = rndFunc();

    delete[] foo; //this is the issue, I get an invalid pointer error.

}
```

Comment: What is `bar` in your Function?

Comment: I messed up my code example -- bar is supposed to be rndValue.

Comment: @HighMans Learn to copy/paste and then you won't mess up your example. Right now how can we trust that you haven't made some other kind of mess up? If you have messed something else up you might not get the right answer, and you'd just be wasting your and everyone else's time. So please use copy/paste and ensure the code you're asking about is ***exactly*** what you're struggling with.

Comment: Going back to my previous comment, I don't get the error you indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are two mistakes in:

```
int* rndFunc(){
    int *rndValue = new int[5]; // instead of int *rndValue = new *int[5];

    return rndValue; // Instead of return bar;
}
```

Comment: Following your first fix gives me this: 

error: expected type-specifier before ‘*’ token
     int *rndValue = new *int[5];

Comment: This should work. My fix compiles fine. Are you sure you removed the second "*" before int[5] in that line??

Comment: Your error still says:  int *rndValue = new *int[5].

Comment: int *rndValue = new *int[5] ---->  int *rndValue = new int[5]

Comment: Oh okay! I got it now. Thank you.